# Scalable cloud storage

Tags: web, streaming, cloud, storage

I'm going to publish a video in a Web page for streaming. I expect having more than 100.000 visits per day in a month. I want to upload my video to a server (or service) that offers the same band-with for all the clients, even if there are hundreds of thousands of clients connected simultaneously.

I will connect the player with the external video.

Note: I cannot use Youtube or Vimeo because the video is 360º technology, so I need to use my custom player.

Please, could you suggest any service that offers this feature?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say this is mostly a question of the streaming technology you'd like use but not the storage alone.
E.g. if you wish to stream via some binary protocol like RTMP, you'll have to use software like Wowza for transcoding and delivery. Hence the load balancing for proper usage of bandwidth will also be served via load balancer like Wowza.

So you should decide what protocols and other technologies you plan using. This will narrow your search parameters.